# I do not want animation in the begin updates, end updates block for uitableview?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that is using a custom table cell and each cell has a UIWebView.

Because UIWebView took along time to load, i want to avoid reloading them at all cost.
In some situations, I have all cells loaded, but their heights are messed up.
Therefore, I need to "relayout" the table without triggering the "cellForRow" function.

1. I definitely cannot use reloadData... as it will reload the cells again.
2. I tried tableView.setNeedDisplay, setNeedsLayout etc, none of them is able to rearrange the table cells
3. The only way it worked, is to call beginupdates/endupdates block, this block is able to relayout my table without firing cellForRow! BUT, I didnt want the animation! This block produces an animation effect but i do not want it...

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: This is great! I find it has some most interesting applications. I found that reload sections method will always animate even if you pass in ```UITableViewRowAnimationNone```, but with this the animation can be easily bypassed!

Answer (score 84):

One more way to do it using blocks

**Obj-C**

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
   [self.tableView beginUpdates];
   [self.tableView endUpdates];
}];
```

**Swift**

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swifties**
I had to do the following for this to work:

```
// Sadly, this is not as simple as calling:
//      UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
//      self.tableView.beginUpdates()
//      self.tableView.endUpdates()
//      UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

// We need to disable the animations.
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
CATransaction.begin()

// And we also need to set the completion block,
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
    // of the animation.
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}

// Call the stuff we need to.
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()

// Commit the animation.
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Helped me. Thanks. Important to put `setAnimationsEnabled(true)` inside the completion block.

Comment: But this does not update Footer until you scroll the tableview.

Comment: @Mr.Bean what's the full case? (i.e. does your tableview always have a footer, are you trying to insert one or remove one?)

Comment: Always have a Footer, just need to update the footer (i.e. There are 2 views inside the footer, need to hide/unhide the views depending on the condition.)

Comment: @Mr.Bean what does your update block contain?  The most extendable method here would be to reload the section.

Answer (score 5):

working on my project, but not a common solution.

```
let loc = tableView.contentOffset
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {

    tableView.reloadData()

    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
tableView.setContentOffset(loc, animated: true)//animation true may perform better
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have a smooth transition:

```
CGPoint offset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
[UIView transitionWithView:self.tableView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;
    } completion:nil];
```

give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS disable animations in UITableView**

From iOS v11 you should use the `performBatchUpdates` method instead of `beginUpdates/endUpdates`

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.tableView.performBatchUpdates {
        //table view updates
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to updated the cell height for section 5 and following code worked for me:

```
UiView.setAnimationsEnabled(False)
self.productTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: SectionType.ProductDescription.hashValue), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
self.productTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 5), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

for OBJ-C

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

for swift

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case worked this:

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    return true
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```