# Refresh UITableView tableFooterView without reloading whole table data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table with section footers and table footer. It receives data from core data. When data change, I have no problem reloading both each single data and section footers, but can't be able to reload the `tableFooterView`.

I have something like that:

```
1
2
3
Section footer: 6
4
5
Section footer: 9
Table footer: 15
```

The main issue is that I have an animation on `-willDisplayCell` and every time I do `[self.tableView reloadData]` it fires on every cell and is a mess. I can't find out how to reload just the table footer. Any ideas will be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309929/i-do-not-want-animation-in-the-begin-updates-end-updates-block-for-uitableview).

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `setNeedsLayout` on your tableFooterView, then `layoutIfNeeded` on your tableView?  I don't know if that will trigger all those cell animations though.

Comment: I tried and don't trigger the animations, but didn't update the tableFooterView.